# What is the correct way of getting a base (or short?) hostname?

Tags: python

Is there a simpler/better or more pythonic way of getting the base hostname?

```
base_hostname = socket.gethostname().split(".")[0]
```

As an example, how would I get localhost only as below:

```
>>> socket.gethostname()
'localhost.localdomain'
>>> socket.getfqdn()
'localhost.localdomain'
>>> socket.gethostname().split('.')[0]
'localhost'
```

I am asking because I suspect there is something similar to the `os.path`'s `abspath`, `basename`, `join`, `split`, `splitext`, etc functions to manipulate hostnames, but I haven't found it yet.

Comment: What do you mean by short hostname?

Comment: @thefourtheye : that is part of my problem: I can't qualify what I want properly I suspect, but I think the .split(".")[0] expresses it precisely.

Comment: `socket.gethostname()` gives the same result.

Comment: @isonix Hmmm, then I can only suggest one improvement. Use the `numsplit` option in `split` function.

Answer (score 12):

You can make it a bit more pythonic by splitting the string only once, at most:

```
import socket
socket.gethostname().split('.', 1)[0]
```

Also, if for some reason you don't want or can't use the `socket` package, an alternative is to use the `platform` package:

```
import platform
platform.node().split('.', 1)[0]
```